# Unable able to toggle layers in ArcGIS Online on/off?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online

I recently published a map as a service from ArcMap for Desktop to ArcGIS Online. I wanted to provide a web map for our customers to access and to interact with. The layers that I uploaded were a combination of vector (Roads, Waterbodies) and raster layers (Elevation, Land use).

However, after I published the layers, my expectation is that the user will be able to toggle on/off the layers as I do in the Desktop environment. That is not the case. I'm not sure why in ArcGIS Online I am unable to do so?

[image]

I haven't found another question that assists in me trying to figure out the answer as well as I have tried re-uploading using different approaches, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done this myself but I found [Toggle layer visibility](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=095dd874c5424028aca99a293079450e) which may help because it can:

> Create a list of layers in a map service and display each layer name
>   along with a check box that allows end-users to toggle layer
>   visibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It was helpful however, the  Dynamically create layer list link brings up the same link as the toggle layer visibility.